# Unable to restore a big table in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm new to mysql.I have a 127GB size ibd table file to restore. While running "alter table shiwangini_test2.mytable import tablespace ;" -it's just running out of memory and stopping mysql service. I know it's binary file. However, is there any alternative way to split/restore this file without hitting high memory usage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You tell nothing about metadata (.cfg) file. Maybe the tablespace was not correctly prepared for copying on source server? Check [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Importing InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-table-import.html), "Prerequisites" and "Importing Tables".

Comment: Thanks @Akina. I'm new to mysql. This .cfg file I didn't create. Let me create this one and try

Comment: The process must be **absolutely precise** !!! even each comma and linebreak in the rules makes sense - perform all steps with absolute precision and accuracy, letter-by-letter.

Comment: @Akina - sorry,I'm not importing these ibd files from any running server. I have copied these files from a backup. So, in this case - i think .cfg file will not be created.. right?

Comment: *I have copied these files from a backup.* .ibd without complete FLUSH TABLES ... FOR EXPORT (,cfg is created during this process) is not applicable for importing.

Comment: That is just a `TABLE`, not a `PARTITION`?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: What MySQL version was the backup?  What version is the target?

Comment: Both are on mysql 5.7

Comment: also, it was just a full table